# Static route with button_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Is there a way to have the equivalent of

```
<%= link_to "Continue", "/profile" %>
```

but with a button_to? From what I understand you have to use a rails route. like new_user_path or something.

I was thinking something like this

```
<%= button_to "Continue", "/profile", method: :get %>
```

let me know if it's possible, and if not then some maybe my best alternative... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can use just a string. So `<%= button_to "Continue", "/profile", { :method => :get }  %>` provides

```
<form action="/profile" class="button_to" method="get">
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: That is, but i'm wanting the get method instead of post since i'm just displaying static content